# CSS line height resizing browser text

Tags: html, css

I am no guru at CSS so please excuse what might be a basic question. I have an annoying problem which I can't seem to fix:

Here is my text without CSS line-height:
[image]

I would like to move the text up closer to the heading tags so I did this:

```
<h2>Loren Ipsum Dol Tjovanuu</h2>
<p style="line-height:0px;">
<i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ...</i>
</p>
<h2>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</h2>
<p style="line-height:0px;">
<i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscin.</i>
</p>
```

**The Result**

[image]

The result is perfect and exactly what I want, but... the problem comes when I resize the browser.

**Problem Resizing the browser**
[image]

**My Question**

Why is the text condensing on browser resize? What am I doing wrong? Should I not use the `line-height` property? Any workaround for this?

Comment: When you give the `line-height` property, that decides the distance between the lines.

Comment: Get rid off `line-height` property and play with `margin` and `padding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
h2 {
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

`h2` tags have margins by default

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k35qrqtb/)

Answer (score 3):

The `line-height` property is used to control how much vertical space is allocated for each line. In general, it is used to adjust how much space there is between lines within an element.

`line-height: 1` means that lines are exactly big enough to fit the tallest letters and lowest descenders, with no space between. A `line-height` of more than 1 means there is some extra space between lines, and less than 1 will result in lines overlapping.

`line-height: 0` means that a line of text has no vertical space allocated to it, so all lines will overlap each other in one line. That is what you are seeing here: the text is wrapping onto a second line, which is rendered over the top of the first line.

What you are trying to do is adjust the space between elements, not the space between lines in a single element. For this, the recommended approach is to adjust either `margin` or `padding`. Consider adjusting the margins of your elements until you have your desired vertical rhythm.

For a really detailed explanation of how all three properties work, see this [*CSS Tricks* article on the box model](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

### Example

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.cramped h2 {
  margin: 0.4em 0 0.2em;
}

.cramped p {
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="cramped">
  <h2>Loren Ipsum Dol Tjovanuu</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ...</p>
  <h2>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscin.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
     <h2>Loren Ipsum Dol Tjovanuu</h2>
    <p style="line-height:23px;">
    <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ...</i>
     </p>
    <h2>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</h2>
    <p style="line-height:23px;">
    <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscin.</i>
    </p>
```

try this it works fine on my browser

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
p{margin-top:-10px; font-style:italic;}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    h2{font-size:18px;}
        p{font-size:14px}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Line height usage is for setting the distance (height) of each line. 0 value gives no distance so you have this problem.

You should let the line-height in the default value and reset default `h2` and `p` element margin.

> line-height
>
> On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the
>   minimum height of line boxes within the element.
>
> On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that
>   is used to calculate line box height. On replaced inline elements such
>   as buttons or other input element, line-height has no effect. [1]

```css
h2, p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Loren Ipsum Dol Tjovanuu</h2>
<p>
  <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit ...</i>
</p>
<h2>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</h2>
<p>
  <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscin.</i>
</p>
```

Reference: [MDN - line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) - [w3.org - line-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)